# Elasticsearch count distinct nested values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with structure as following

```
{
  "_source": {
    "nested_obj": [
      {
        "data_id": "123"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to count all distinct occurences of `data_id` but I'm not sure if such query is accurate?

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "nested_properties": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "nested_obj"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "nested_obj.data_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value_count` metric aggregation does not count distinct values but all values. What you need is the [`cardinality` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html), but you need to know that the [counts will be approximate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate) depending on whether the `data_id` field is high-cardinality or not.

You can have some control of the [precision threshold](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_precision_control), though.

Comment: Thank you, I still don't understand why executing "my query" the results is: "aggregations" : {
    "nested_properties" : {
      "doc_count" : 98759,
      "count" : {
        "value" : 98743
      }
    } 
Why doc_count is different than value?

Comment: Which aggregation did you try? value_count or cardinality?

Comment: value_count, the exact one from above

Comment: Though value_count doesn't provide you with a distinct count as you expect.

Comment: Assuming data_id property will have only unique values, then value_count should be sufficient. Still I don't know why there's the difference between doc_cound and value.

Comment: Do you have only a single nested document inside `nested_obj`?

Comment: No, there can be multiple.

Comment: And the same data_id can be in different parent documents? or each data_id is unique across all nested and parent documents?

Comment: Can you run a `terms` aggregation instead of `value_count` and let us know if one or more top buckets have doc_count = 2 ?